# How to launch Safari to a specific URL from Springboard in custom iOS theme?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I've been working on modifying the [Boxor HD Theme](http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-4-new-skins-themes-launches/760772-boxor-hd.html) by changing icons, apps, etc.

For one of the large icons on the "Springboard", I'd like it to open to Google News in Safari when pressed -- so not just have it load Safari, but to load that specific URL as well.

I know I can use "launch com.apple.mobilesafari" to launch Safari, but that doesn't really launch the URL specifically. I also tried defining a custom function, but couldn't quite get it to open Safari either (I was using that simply as a starting point).

Here's my code for the icon:

```
<dict>
    <key>Actions</key>
    <array>
        <string>function openURLp</string>
    </array>
    <key>Frame</key>
    <string>165,295,145,100</string>
    <key>Image</key>
    <string>$ROOT/SBicons/News.png</string>
    <key>ViewType</key>
    <string>Button</string>
</dict>'
```

And here's my simple code for a function (which is of course located within the Functions section):

```
<key>OpenURLp</key>
<array>
    <string>launch com.apple.mobilesafari</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourWebsiteHere.com"]];
```

Comment: I've seen that code many times, and even tried it -- my understanding is that it's for use within an actual app's code, rather than a theme's file. Though perhaps I'm using it wrong -- would I just replace the URL and just place this within the <string> tags?